# Why is it necessary to explicitly convert a Numpy element before giving it to Qt?

Tags: python, numpy, pyqt, pyqt4

Feeding an element of a `NumPy` array to `Qt.QColor` results in unexpected behavior:

```
from PyQt4 import Qt
import numpy as np

z = np.zeros((3, 3), dtype=np.uint32)
z[0, 0] = 0xAABBCC
c = Qt.QColor(z[0, 0]) # !!!
print c.red(), c.green(), c.blue() # prints (0, 0, 0)
```

However,

```
c = Qt.QColor(int(z[0, 0])
```

works as expected. Why is that?

**Versions:** Standard Ubuntu 14.04 (amd64) versions:

- python 2.7.5
- numpy 1.8.2
- python-qt4 4.10.4

Comment: Numpy uses its own data types, so the value `z[0,0]` is not a "real" Python int.  I could imagine that Qt is doing some typechecking or making assumptions about the innards of the values you give it, so it won't work for "int-like" values but only for real Python ints.  I don't know for sure exactly what it's doing though.

Comment: You will need to give more details about which version of PyQt4, numpy and python you are using because with my configuration (`python 3`, `numpy 1.9.2` and `PyQt4 4.10.4`), your code is working.

Comment: `type(z[0, 0])` `<type 'numpy.uint32'>` and `type(int(z[0, 0]))` `<type 'int'>`. I guess internally qt4 checks for the standard python `int` and this fails for the `numpy.uint32`.

Comment: I think @abudis answer is correct and he should put it in as an answer for you to accept.  The `QtColor` constructor has many forms and uses (the C equivalent of) `isinstance` to decide which to use.